# How do I set cookie in nextjs from a separate backend server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a nodejs API built with express.js and the cookie I set work well on postman but it doesn't seem to work on nextjs. I set the cookie once a user logs-in but it don't see it on the cookie session of the browser and it is not included in my api request from nextjs.
The cookie set in backend:

```
 res.cookie("refreshJWT", userRefreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 604800000,
    });
```

My server cors:

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));
```

The login in nextjs.

```
const handleClick = async()=>{
    try {
        dispatch({type: actionEnum.ISLOADING_START});

        const userData = {
            username: logDetails.username,
            password: logDetails.password,
        }
        const response = await axios.post<axiosLogResAttributes>(`${BASE_URL}/login`, userData);
        
            localStorage.setItem('refresh', response?.data.userRefreshToken);
            localStorage.setItem('token', response?.data.userToken)
            dispatch({type: actionEnum.SET_USER_REFRESH, payload: response?.data.userRefreshToken});
            //dispatch({type: actionEnum.SET_IN_MEMORY_VARIABLE, payload: response?.data.userToken})
            
             
            dispatch({type: actionEnum.ISLOADING_END})

          router.push('/')
          
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: actionEnum.ISLOADING_END}) 
    }
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add withCredentials in axios

```
    const response = await axios.post<axiosLogResAttributes>(
      `${BASE_URL}/login`,
      userData,
      { withCredentials: true } 
    );
```